# CSS: Why is my body selector not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently doing some CSS work for my class and for some reason the body selector won't work. The other selectors in the style tag work but this one doesn't work. Not really sure why so help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <style type="text/css">

    @import "navbar.css"

    body {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #0d4a2c;
      line-height: 1.25em;
    }

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #container {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid;
      background-color: #c2efd8;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please provide us your HTML and navbar.css aswell?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like a missing `;` after your `@import "navbar.css"`.

```
<style type="text/css">

    @import "navbar.css";

    body {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #0d4a2c;
      line-height: 1.25em;
    }

    * {
      margins: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #container {
      width: 90%;
      margins: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid;
      background-color: #c2efd8;
    }
```